# Video not playing on Apple products

Tags: html, ios, html5-video

I'm playing a video through the browser using:

```
    <video class="video">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
```

It's not working on Apple's through Firefox which I understand is because I'm using the H.264.  How do I render to play on an Apple with Firefox as well?

Comment: I don't think MP4 is supported by FF on Mac out of the box so will require a user to install a plugin - Read more here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox

Comment: @SausedApples - I recognise it is not supported out of the box and if users haven't installed the plugin then I need an alternative format for the video.  I'm asking what is the best alternative and how do I implement it without upsetting the other browsers?

Comment: is the solution to make a copy as a webm file and then add `<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />` after the mp4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video class="video">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
</video>
```